# Python/Database Website development

Tags: web-development, python, database, server

I want to create my own website that would allow me to acess a database in the server and do inserts and lookups in a user friendly way. I am a seasoned user of linux and C/C++, and also have experience with Python and sqlite3, but i don't have any experience in Web development, so i have no idea where to start.

I have researched online and the best i came up with was an Apache/Nginx server together with an fcig or wscgi and Django, so that i would have database and python integration through a Django App.

Can someone tell me if this is the way to go or if there is some easier (or better) way to accomplish what i want?

Comment: If you're not doing anything asynchronous (e.g. with Twisted, Tornado or GEvent), then the stack is usually either Django or Flask, with either Apache+mod_wsgi or nginx+uwsgi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you know Python already I see no reason not to go for Django. It should be fairly easy to set up and try out a quick project to see if you like it. Like with everything there's a learning curve, but from what I've seen the tutorials and documentation to get you up and running is rather good.

Answer (score -7):

PHP would be easier.  Its also C-like. But it takes less of a learning curve to move into webdevelopment with because its basically designed primarily for webdevelopment. Plus they have good documentation at PHP.NET

See [Is there anyone who has used Python/Ruby and PHP for a long time and still prefer PHP?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/22742/is-there-anyone-who-has-used-python-ruby-and-php-for-a-long-time-and-still-prefe/22784#22784)

Comment: Really, this is advice you give to someone with Python experience? How much experience do you have with Python web development yourself?

Comment: The answer you cited is three years old, and its only specific point against Python is not currently true. In fact, it probably never was.